# Using text inside \num from siunitx

Tags: formatting, siunitx

Consider this TikZ drawing of the table of elements (taken from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/periodic-table-of-chemical-elements/) and edited a bit):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\usepackage[
  active,
  tightpage
]{preview}
\usepackage[
  locale=DE,
  input-decimal-markers={,}
]{siunitx}

\ifpdf

\else
  \usepackage{pst-all}
\fi

\begin{comment}
:Title: Grundstoffernes periodiske system
\end{comment}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\CommonElementTextFormat}[4]{%
  \begin{minipage}{2.2cm}
    \centering
      {\textbf{#1} \hfill #2}% <----- Here, I would like to change `#2' to `\num{#2}'.
      \linebreak \linebreak
      {\textbf{#3}}%
      \linebreak \linebreak
      {{#4}}
  \end{minipage}
}

\newcommand{\NaturalElementTextFormat}[4]{%
  \CommonElementTextFormat{#1}{#2}{\LARGE {#3}}{#4}
}

\newcommand{\OutlineText}[1]{%
  \ifpdf
    \pdfliteral direct {0.5 w 1 Tr}{#1}%
    \pdfliteral direct {1 w 0 Tr}%
  \else
    % PSTricks kan gøre dette med \pscharpath.
    \pscharpath[
      shadow=false,
      fillstyle=solid,
      fillcolor=white,
      linestyle=solid,
      linecolor=black,
      linewidth=0.2pt
    ]{#1} 
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\SyntheticElementTextFormat}[4]{%
  \ifpdf
    \CommonElementTextFormat{#1}{#2}{\OutlineText{\LARGE #3}}{#4}
  \else
    % PSTricks giver output, der er en smule større, så vi skal have lavet boksen lidt mindre.
    \CommonElementTextFormat{#1}{#2}{\OutlineText{\Large #3}}{#4}
  \fi
}

\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, scale=0.45, transform shape]

% Farveudfyldning af elementpladser.
  \tikzstyle{ElementFill}            = [fill=yellow!15]
  \tikzstyle{AlkaliMetalFill}        = [fill=blue!55]
  \tikzstyle{AlkalineEarthMetalFill} = [fill=blue!40]
  \tikzstyle{TransitionMetalFill}    = [fill=blue!25]
  \tikzstyle{MetalFill}              = [fill=blue!15]
  \tikzstyle{MetalloidFill}          = [fill=orange!25]
  \tikzstyle{NonmetalFill}           = [fill=green!25]
  \tikzstyle{HalogenFill}            = [fill=green!40]
  \tikzstyle{NobleGasFill}           = [fill=green!55]
  \tikzstyle{LanthanideActinideFill} = [fill=purple!25]

% Opsætning af elementpladser.
  \tikzstyle{Element}            = [draw=black, ElementFill, minimum width=2.75cm, minimum height=2.75cm, node distance=2.75cm]
  \tikzstyle{AlkaliMetal}        = [Element, AlkaliMetalFill]
  \tikzstyle{AlkalineEarthMetal} = [Element, AlkalineEarthMetalFill]
  \tikzstyle{TransitionMetal}    = [Element, TransitionMetalFill]
  \tikzstyle{Metal}              = [Element, MetalFill]
  \tikzstyle{Metalloid}          = [Element, MetalloidFill]
  \tikzstyle{Nonmetal}           = [Element, NonmetalFill]
  \tikzstyle{Halogen}            = [Element, HalogenFill]
  \tikzstyle{NobleGas}           = [Element, NobleGasFill]
  \tikzstyle{LanthanideActinide} = [Element, LanthanideActinideFill]
  \tikzstyle{PeriodLabel}        = [font={\LARGE\sffamily}, node distance=2.0cm]
  \tikzstyle{GroupLabel}         = [font={\LARGE\sffamily}, minimum width=2.75cm, node distance=2.0cm]
  \tikzstyle{TitleLabel}         = [font={\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}]

% Gruppe 1 - IA
  \node[name=H,  Element]                  {\NaturalElementTextFormat{1}{1,00794}{H}{Hydrogen}};
  \node[name=Li, below of=H,  AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{3}{6,941}{Li}{Litium}};
  \node[name=Na, below of=Li, AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{11}{22,9897693}{Na}{Natrium}};
  \node[name=K,  below of=Na, AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{19}{39,0983}{K}{Kalium}};
  \node[name=Rb, below of=K,  AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{37}{85,4678}{Rb}{Rubidium}};
  \node[name=Cs, below of=Rb, AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{55}{132,90545196}{Cs}{C{\ae}sium}};
  \node[name=Fr, below of=Cs, AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{87}{223,0197}{Fr}{Francium}};

% Gruppe 2 - IIA
  \node[name=Be, right of=Li, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{4}{9,0121831}{Be}{Beryllium}};
  \node[name=Mg, below of=Be, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{12}{24,3050}{Mg}{Magnesium}};
  \node[name=Ca, below of=Mg, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{20}{40,078}{Ca}{Calcium}};
  \node[name=Sr, below of=Ca, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{38}{87,62}{Sr}{Strontium}};
  \node[name=Ba, below of=Sr, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{56}{137,327}{Ba}{Barium}};
  \node[name=Ra, below of=Ba, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{88}{226,0254}{Ra}{Radium}};

% Gruppe 3 - IIIB
  \node[name=Sc,   right of=Ca,   TransitionMetal]    {\NaturalElementTextFormat{21}{44,955908}{Sc}{Scandium}};
  \node[name=Y,    below of=Sc,   TransitionMetal]    {\NaturalElementTextFormat{39}{88,90584}{Y}{Yttrium}};
  \node[name=LaLu, below of=Y,    LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{57--71}{}{La--Lu}{Lanthanider}};
  \node[name=AcLr, below of=LaLu, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{89--103}{}{Ac--\OutlineText{\kern -6pt Lr}}{Actinider}};

% Gruppe 4 - IVB
  \node[name=Ti, right of=Sc, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{22}{47,867}{Ti}{Titanium}};
  \node[name=Zr, below of=Ti, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{40}{91,224}{Zr}{Zirkonium}};
  \node[name=Hf, below of=Zr, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{72}{178,49}{Hf}{Hafnium}};
  \node[name=Rf, below of=Hf, TransitionMetal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{104}{261,1088}{Rf}{Rutherfordium}};

% Gruppe 5 - VB
  \node[name=V,  right of=Ti, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{23}{50,9415}{V}{Vanadium}};
  \node[name=Nb, below of=V,  TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{41}{92,90637}{Nb}{Niobium}};
  \node[name=Ta, below of=Nb, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{73}{180,94788}{Ta}{Tantal}};
  \node[name=Db, below of=Ta, TransitionMetal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{105}{262,1141}{Db}{Dubnium}};

% Gruppe 6 - VIB
  \node[name=Cr, right of=V,  TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{24}{51,9961}{Cr}{Krom}};
  \node[name=Mo, below of=Cr, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{42}{95,95}{Mo}{Molybd{\ae}n}};
  \node[name=W,  below of=Mo, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{74}{183,84}{W}{Wolfram}};
  \node[name=Sg, below of=W,  TransitionMetal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{106}{266,1219}{Sg}{Seaborgium}};

% Gruppe 7 - VIIB
  \node[name=Mn, right of=Cr, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{25}{54,938044}{Mn}{Mangan}};
  \node[name=Tc, below of=Mn, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{43}{97,9072}{Tc}{Technetium}};
  \node[name=Re, below of=Tc, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{75}{186,207}{Re}{Rhenium}};
  \node[name=Bh, below of=Re, TransitionMetal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{107}{264,12}{Bh}{Bohrium}};

% Gruppe 8 - VIIIB
  \node[name=Fe, right of=Mn, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{26}{55,845}{Fe}{Jern}};
  \node[name=Ru, below of=Fe, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{44}{101,07}{Ru}{Ruthenium}};
  \node[name=Os, below of=Ru, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{76}{190,23}{Os}{Osmium}};
  \node[name=Hs, below of=Os, TransitionMetal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{108}{277}{Hs}{Hassium}};

% Gruppe 9 - VIIIB
  \node[name=Co, right of=Fe, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{27}{58,933194}{Co}{Kobolt}};
  \node[name=Rh, below of=Co, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{45}{102,90550}{Rh}{Rhodium}};
  \node[name=Ir, below of=Rh, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{77}{192,217}{Ir}{Iridium}};
  \node[name=Mt, below of=Ir, TransitionMetal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{109}{268,1388}{Mt}{Meitnerium}};

% Gruppe 10 - VIIIB
  \node[name=Ni, right of=Co, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{28}{58,6934}{Ni}{Nikkel}};
  \node[name=Pd, below of=Ni, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{46}{106,42}{Pd}{Palladium}};
  \node[name=Pt, below of=Pd, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{78}{195,084}{Pt}{Platin}};
  \node[name=Ds, below of=Pt, TransitionMetal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{110}{271}{Ds}{Darmstadtium}};

% Gruppe 11 - IB
  \node[name=Cu, right of=Ni, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{29}{63,546}{Cu}{Kobber}};
  \node[name=Ag, below of=Cu, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{47}{107,8682}{Ag}{S{\o}lv}};
  \node[name=Au, below of=Ag, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{79}{196,966569}{Au}{Guld}};
  \node[name=Rg, below of=Au, TransitionMetal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{111}{272,1535}{Rg}{R{\o}ntgenium}};

% Gruppe 12 - IIB
  \node[name=Zn,  right of=Cu, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{30}{65,38}{Zn}{Zink}};
  \node[name=Cd,  below of=Zn, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{48}{112,414}{Cd}{Cadmium}};
  \node[name=Hg,  below of=Cd, TransitionMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{80}{200,59}{Hg}{Kviks{\o}lv}};
  \node[name=Uub, below of=Hg, TransitionMetal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{112}{285}{Cn}{Kopernikium}};

% Gruppe 13 - IIIA
  \node[name=Ga,  right of=Zn, Metal]     {\NaturalElementTextFormat{31}{69,723}{Ga}{Gallium}};
  \node[name=Al,  above of=Ga, Metal]     {\NaturalElementTextFormat{13}{26,9815385}{Al}{Aluminium}};
  \node[name=B,   above of=Al, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{5}{10,811}{B}{Bor}};
  \node[name=In,  below of=Ga, Metal]     {\NaturalElementTextFormat{49}{114,818}{In}{Indium}};
  \node[name=Tl,  below of=In, Metal]     {\NaturalElementTextFormat{81}{204,3833}{Tl}{Tallium}};
  \node[name=Uut, below of=Tl, Metal]     {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{113}{286}{Uut}{Ununtrium}};

% Gruppe 14 - IVA
  \node[name=C,   right of=B,  Nonmetal]  {\NaturalElementTextFormat{6}{12,0107}{C}{Carbon}};
  \node[name=Si,  below of=C,  Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{14}{28,0855}{Si}{Silicium}};
  \node[name=Ge,  below of=Si, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{32}{72,64}{Ge}{Germanium}};
  \node[name=Sn,  below of=Ge, Metal]     {\NaturalElementTextFormat{50}{118,710}{Sn}{Tin}};
  \node[name=Pb,  below of=Sn, Metal]     {\NaturalElementTextFormat{82}{207,2}{Pb}{Bly}};
  \node[name=Uuq, below of=Pb, Metal]     {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{114}{289}{Uuq}{Ununquadium}};

% Gruppe 15 - VA
  \node[name=N,   right of=C,  Nonmetal]  {\NaturalElementTextFormat{7}{14,0067}{N}{Nitrogen}};
  \node[name=P,   below of=N,  Nonmetal]  {\NaturalElementTextFormat{15}{30,973761998}{P}{Fosfor}};
  \node[name=As,  below of=P,  Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{33}{74,921595}{As}{Arsen}};
  \node[name=Sb,  below of=As, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{51}{121,760}{Sb}{Antimon}};
  \node[name=Bi,  below of=Sb, Metal]     {\NaturalElementTextFormat{83}{208,98040}{Bi}{Bismuth}};
  \node[name=Uup, below of=Bi, Metal]     {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{115}{288}{Uup}{Ununpentium}};

% Gruppe 16 - VIA
  \node[name=O,   right of=N,  Nonmetal]  {\NaturalElementTextFormat{8}{15,9994}{O}{Oxygen}};
  \node[name=S,   below of=O,  Nonmetal]  {\NaturalElementTextFormat{16}{32,065}{S}{Svovl}};
  \node[name=Se,  below of=S,  Nonmetal]  {\NaturalElementTextFormat{34}{78,971}{Se}{Selen}};
  \node[name=Te,  below of=Se, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{52}{127,60}{Te}{Tellur}};
  \node[name=Po,  below of=Te, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{84}{208,9824}{Po}{Polonium}};
  \node[name=Uuh, below of=Po, Metal]     {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{116}{289}{Uuh}{Ununhexium}};

% Gruppe 17 - VIIA
  \node[name=F,   right of=O,  Halogen] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{9}{18,998403163}{F}{Flour}};
  \node[name=Cl,  below of=F,  Halogen] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{17}{35,453}{Cl}{Klor}};
  \node[name=Br,  below of=Cl, Halogen] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{35}{79,904}{Br}{Brom}};
  \node[name=I,   below of=Br, Halogen] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{53}{126,90447}{I}{Jod}};
  \node[name=At,  below of=I,  Halogen] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{85}{209,9871}{At}{Astat}};
  \node[name=Uus, below of=At, Element] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{117}{292}{Uus}{Ununseptium}}; 

% Gruppe 18 - VIIIA
  \node[name=Ne,  right of=F,  NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{10}{20,1797}{Ne}{Neon}};
  \node[name=He,  above of=Ne, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{2}{4,002602}{He}{Helium}};
  \node[name=Ar,  below of=Ne, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{18}{39,948}{Ar}{Argon}};
  \node[name=Kr,  below of=Ar, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{36}{83,798}{Kr}{Krypton}};
  \node[name=Xe,  below of=Kr, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{54}{131,293}{Xe}{Xenon}};
  \node[name=Rn,  below of=Xe, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{86}{222,0176}{Rn}{Radon}};
  \node[name=Uuo, below of=Rn, NobleGas] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{118}{293}{Uuo}{Ununoctium}}; 

% Perioder.
  \node[name=Period1, left of=H,  PeriodLabel] {1};
  \node[name=Period2, left of=Li, PeriodLabel] {2};
  \node[name=Period3, left of=Na, PeriodLabel] {3}; 
  \node[name=Period4, left of=K,  PeriodLabel] {4}; 
  \node[name=Period5, left of=Rb, PeriodLabel] {5};
  \node[name=Period6, left of=Cs, PeriodLabel] {6};
  \node[name=Period7, left of=Fr, PeriodLabel] {7};

% Grupper.
  \node[name=Group1,  above of=H,  GroupLabel]  {1 \hfill IA};
  \node[name=Group2,  above of=Be, GroupLabel]  {2 \hfill IIA};
  \node[name=Group3,  above of=Sc, GroupLabel]  {3 \hfill IIIB};
  \node[name=Group4,  above of=Ti, GroupLabel]  {4 \hfill IVB};
  \node[name=Group5,  above of=V,  GroupLabel]  {5 \hfill VB};
  \node[name=Group6,  above of=Cr, GroupLabel]  {6 \hfill VIB};
  \node[name=Group7,  above of=Mn, GroupLabel]  {7 \hfill VIIB};
  \node[name=Group8,  above of=Fe, GroupLabel]  {8 \hfill VIIIB};
  \node[name=Group9,  above of=Co, GroupLabel]  {9 \hfill VIIIB};
  \node[name=Group10, above of=Ni, GroupLabel] {10 \hfill VIIIB};
  \node[name=Group11, above of=Cu, GroupLabel] {11 \hfill IB};
  \node[name=Group12, above of=Zn, GroupLabel] {12 \hfill IIB};
  \node[name=Group13, above of=B,  GroupLabel] {13 \hfill IIIA};
  \node[name=Group14, above of=C,  GroupLabel] {14 \hfill IVA};
  \node[name=Group15, above of=N,  GroupLabel] {15 \hfill VA};
  \node[name=Group16, above of=O,  GroupLabel] {16 \hfill VIA};
  \node[name=Group17, above of=F,  GroupLabel] {17 \hfill VIIA};
  \node[name=Group18, above of=He, GroupLabel] {18 \hfill VIIIA};

% lanthanider.
  \node[name=La, below of=Rf, LanthanideActinide, yshift=-1cm] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{57}{138,90547}{La}{Lanthan}};
  \node[name=Ce, right of=La, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{58}{140,116}{Ce}{Cerium}};
  \node[name=Pr, right of=Ce, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{59}{140,90766}{Pr}{Praseodym}};
  \node[name=Nd, right of=Pr, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{60}{144,242}{Nd}{Neodym}};
  \node[name=Pm, right of=Nd, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{61}{144,9127}{Pm}{Promethium}};
  \node[name=Sm, right of=Pm, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{62}{150,36}{Sm}{Samarium}};
  \node[name=Eu, right of=Sm, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{63}{151,964}{Eu}{Europium}};
  \node[name=Gd, right of=Eu, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{64}{157,25}{Gd}{Gadolinium}};
  \node[name=Tb, right of=Gd, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{65}{158,92535}{Tb}{Terbium}};
  \node[name=Dy, right of=Tb, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{66}{162,500}{Dy}{Dysprosium}};
  \node[name=Ho, right of=Dy, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{67}{164,93033}{Ho}{Holmium}};
  \node[name=Er, right of=Ho, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{68}{167,259}{Er}{Erbium}};
  \node[name=Tm, right of=Er, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{69}{168,93422}{Tm}{Thulium}};
  \node[name=Yb, right of=Tm, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{70}{173,054}{Yb}{Ytterbium}};
  \node[name=Lu, right of=Yb, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{71}{174,9668}{Lu}{Lutetium}};

% actinider.
  \node[name=Ac, below of=La, LanthanideActinide, yshift=-1cm] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{89}{227,0277}{Ac}{Actinium}};
  \node[name=Th, right of=Ac, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{90}{232,0377}{Th}{Thorium}};
  \node[name=Pa, right of=Th, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{91}{231,03588}{Pa}{Protactinium}};
  \node[name=U , right of=Pa, LanthanideActinide]              {\NaturalElementTextFormat{92}{238,02891}{U}{Uran}};
  \node[name=Np, right of=U,  LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{93}{237,0482}{Np}{Neptunium}};
  \node[name=Pu, right of=Np, LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{94}{244,0642}{Pu}{Plutonium}};
  \node[name=Am, right of=Pu, LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{95}{243,0614}{Am}{Americium}};
  \node[name=Cm, right of=Am, LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{96}{247,0704}{Cm}{Curium}};
  \node[name=Bk, right of=Cm, LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{97}{247,0703}{Bk}{Berkelium}};
  \node[name=Cf, right of=Bk, LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{98}{251,0796}{Cf}{Californium}};
  \node[name=Es, right of=Cf, LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{99}{252,0830}{Es}{Einsteinium}};
  \node[name=Fm, right of=Es, LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{100}{257,0951}{Fm}{Fermium}};
  \node[name=Md, right of=Fm, LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{101}{258,0984}{Md}{Mendelevium}};
  \node[name=No, right of=Md, LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{102}{259,1010}{No}{Nobelium}};
  \node[name=Lr, right of=No, LanthanideActinide]              {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{103}{262,1097}{Lr}{Lawrencium}};

% Prikkede linjer, der forbinder lanthaniderne med hovedtabellen.
  \draw (LaLu.north west) edge[dotted] (La.north west)
        (LaLu.north east) edge[dotted] (Lu.north east)
        (LaLu.south west) edge[dotted] (La.south west)
        (LaLu.south east) edge[dotted] (Lu.south east);

% Prikkede linjer, der forbinder actiniderne med hovedtabellen.
  \draw (AcLr.north west) edge[dotted] (Ac.north west)
        (AcLr.north east) edge[dotted] (Lr.north east)
        (AcLr.south west) edge[dotted] (Ac.south west)
        (AcLr.south east) edge[dotted] (Lr.south east);

% Placering af figurforklaringer.
  \draw[black, AlkaliMetalFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,1.3em)$)
    rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Alkalimetal};
  \draw[black, AlkalineEarthMetalFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-0.2em)$)
    rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Jordalkalimetal};
  \draw[black, TransitionMetalFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-1.7em)$)
    rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Overgangsmetal};
  \draw[black, MetalFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-3.2em)$)
    rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Metal};
  \draw[black, MetalloidFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-4.7em)$)
    rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Halvmetal};
  \draw[black, NonmetalFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-6.2em)$)
    rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Ikke-metal};
  \draw[black, HalogenFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-7.7em)$)
    rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Halogen};
  \draw[black, NobleGasFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-9.2em)$)
    rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{{\AE}delgas};
  \draw[black, LanthanideActinideFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-10.7em)$)
    rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Lanthanoid/Actinid};

  \node at ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (5em,-15em)$) [name=elementLegend, Element, fill=white]
    {\NaturalElementTextFormat{Z}{Masse}{Symbol}{Navn}};
  \node[Element, fill=white, right of=elementLegend, xshift=1em]
    {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{}{}{men\-nes\-ke\-skabt}{}} ;

% Diagramtitel.
  \node at (H.west -| Fe.north) [name=diagramTitle, TitleLabel]
    %{Dmitri I. Mendeleevs periodiske system for grundstofferne};
    {Grundstoffernes periodiske system};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}

\end{document}
```

I would like to change line 30 from

```
{\textbf{#1} \hfill #2}
```

to

```
{\textbf{#1} \hfill \num{#2}}
```

in order to get a nice formatting of the atomic masses, but I can't put text inside `\num`. How do I fix this?

P.S. The problem occurs in line 321.

Comment: `parse-numbers=false` helps?

Comment: @PGFTricks Then the number formatting is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can get here is to define a 'symbol' for input which expands to your text. I'd use `\NewDocumentCommand` for this as `siunitx` will otherwise try to expand stuff. Cutting down to the essentials You need to register this with `siunitx`, and I'd also make sure printing is always in text mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Masse}{}{\text{Masse}}
\sisetup{input-symbols = \Masse}
\begin{document}
\num{1.23456}
\num{\Masse}
\end{document}
```